# jest test in react 18 failing because unable to find testid in react-dom, using createRoot

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom

Using react 18 and looking to write jest tests with version 29.5.0. I'm getting this error when running my jest test `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="/testdiv/i"]` even though element was just rendered, I have also tried putting the expect inside an `await waitFor`. I've used a example div with a test id here as an example to simulate a component I'm importing

Is there a step I'm missing here to let the screen know how to find that test element?

package.json

```
 "react": "^18.2.0",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",

"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "@swc/jest"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "browsers": [
        "chrome",
        "firefox",
        "safari"
      ]
    },
    "globals": {
      "IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT": true
    }
```

jest.setup.js

```
import React from "react";
import { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } from "util";

global.React = React;
Object.assign(global, { TextDecoder, TextEncoder });
```

test file

```
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";

const dom = new JSDOM("<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>");
const document = dom.window.document;
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "app";
document.body.appendChild(div);
const appElement = document.getElementById("app");
const root = createRoot(appElement!);

it("should render", () => {
    root.render(<div data-testid="testdiv">hi</div>);
    expect(screen.getByTestId(/testdiv/i)).toContain("hi");
  });
```

Comment: Have you checked the [official examples](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro)? You need to use the `render` function from the library and not the React's rendering functions.

Comment: Yes I was using that before, I've switched to React 18 and am getting this warning, Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

Comment: You need to switch to `createRoot` for the app (index.js), not the tests, the tests stay the same.